# For how long will legacy component MVC structure work in Joomla?

Tags: component, joomla-4.x, custom-component, mvc, joomla-5.x

Legacy component MVC structure:

```
com_foo
|- controllers
|  |- foo.php
|- helpers
|  |- foo.php
|- models
|  |- forms
|  |  |- foo.xml
|  |- foo.php
|- views
|  |- foo
|  |  |- tmpl
|  |  |  |- default.php
|- foo.php
```

Joomla 4/5 MVC structure:

```
com_foo
|- forms
|  |- foo.xml
|- services
|  |- provider.php
|- src
|- |- Controller
|- |- |- DisplayController.php
|- |- |- FooController.php
|- |- Extension
|- |- |- FooComponent.php
|- |- Helper
|- |- |- FooHelper.php
|- |- Model
|- |- |- FooModel.php
|- |- Table
|- |- |- FooTable.php
|- |- View
|- |- |- Foo
|- |- |- |- HtmlView.php
|- tmpl
|- |- foo
|- |- |- default.php
```

The first structure is now called `LegacyComponent`. Does anyone know if this is announced as deprecated, or in which version will it stop working?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is I don't believe it will 'stop working'. The new structure is guideline or preferred structure that brings Joomla inline with other frameworks. You can have whatever structure you like, including the J3 style, but you may find that you have to put in more specific references to where you have located things as Joomla may start to remove the backward compatibility code that locates things automatically in a future version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you seen by any chance where this structure change was discussed? Perhaps they mention their future plans there.

Comment: I don't recall reading a specific item or article about the change. Like many things Joomla you pick up bits and pieces here and there to form an understanding of what is going on.

Comment: That is true... I have upvoted your answer, but I will wait until we find something official, before setting an answer as the accepted one. I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

According to information from volunteers over at the Joomla Mattermost community, the most up-to-date information is the one found in code comments. I received [this link to Joomla's code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.4-dev/libraries/src/MVC/Model/LegacyModelLoaderTrait.php#L29-L30) that currently says that loading such Legacy structure `will be removed in 6.0 without replacement`.